# Facebook Access token type (app or user) for user_managed_groups

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app that grabs all of the posts from a user's group feed that they admin. When I log into Graph API explorer with my app as the context I can use my app access token to view the posts from my user's managed groups. When I then try to use the same app access token to view my group I get an error:

`Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'someid' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation...`

I'm trying to nail this down for my users but I'm confused now as to which token I should be using when **they** use my app in their context.

It seems that in my case I can use an app access token to read other user's group feed but not my own group feed. When I switch the access token to a user access token I can then read my group feed again.

My question is what is the correct token to use in context when the user is logged in to my app and my app needs to read the user's group feed?

Bonus question why is my app able to read other user's group feed using an app access token?

Comment: Based on some more testing I'm pretty sure the user access token is needed when the user is logged in, however, I still don't know why my app access token is allowed to read the group feed of other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done enough research and testing to say that if a user is logged in and wants to read data from their managed groups then I need to provide their user access token.